# PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock;

Tags: 7

I am getting the following error on my D7 site:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 
Deadlock found when  trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: 
INSERT INTO {node} (type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, promote, sticky) 
VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
:db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
:db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
:db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8); Array
(
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => baby_clothes
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => und
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => Boys clothes and swing
[:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1333240131
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1333240131
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1
[:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 0
)

in drupal_write_record() (line 6975 of includes/common.inc).
```

I have a module that saves nodes programatically on cron run.  There is the possibiliy that two nodes could save simultaneously.  Is that what could be causing this? The table locking mechanism is not working correctly to prevent collisions? If I put the site in maintenance mode and just run the batch of nodes to be saved, this never happens. Thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Where does the `Boys clothes and swing` come from?  Is that from your module?

Comment: Those are example values of what is going into the database node table. They correspond respectively to type, language, title, etc, going top to bottom.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue in drupal 7.x core and has been resolved in the latest release (see [this bug report](http://drupal.org/node/1369332) for more information). Make sure you've upgraded to the latest version of Drupal 7, or try applying the patch if you need to get your site operational.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not true that the current release of Drupal 7 has the fix for this issue. The most recent release is 7.12, which came out in February. This fix was applied to the Drupal core 7.x dev branch in late March, but that branch is not meant to be run on production sites. Hopefully, the next official release of Drupal 7 will be pushed out soon, as it will have this fix.

Comment: Drupal 7.14 contains that fix. But there are still some people encountering these errors even with the fix.

Comment: As of this writing, I am still getting this error (7.15). More thoughts on how to fix this outside of Drupal?

Comment: I opened a new thread concerning this. Have a look as the new thread more generically addresses needing to get around this as a performance issue. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/how-can-i-upload-1000s-of-nodes-per-hour-to-a-live-drupal-7-site-and-avoid-deadl

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this problem. I realized there was some redundant data in the database. After deleting these, the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ Gokul N K The way to go would be to backup your database with Backup and Migrate module ( this makes the data free from unnecessary cache data) - import this data in a database on your local server and check to see if there are redundant rows in any of the field tables (this I assume you would be able to identify as the developer). Delete those records and the import teh clean data into your site. Hope it helps.