# Updating few thousand nodes in one time

Tags: nodes, performance

I have script which updating 2000-5000 nodes in loop and performance is poor.
At the moment the code looks like:

```
foreach($nids as $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  // updating $node fields
  node_save($node);
}
```

It's possible optimize it? I don't need revisions, call node_* hooks, just update data.

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69243/how-can-i-speed-up-drupals-node-save-function

Comment: Yes, but no answer with solution

Comment: One optimisation is to use node_load_multiple, doing 100 nodes at a time.

Comment: You could use drupal batch api to make sure your request doesn't time out.

Comment: These examples should help you get familiar with the batch API: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example!batch_example.module/7

Comment: Modifying this answer is most likely what is needed http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64833/fast-saving-single-field-value

Answer (score 1):

There's a module called [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

This will update more than thousand node at a time without memory limit exception.